# need to change menu bigger height in size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my site:

```
http://tudios.com/
```

I need to make the menu bigger height wise exactly like below image:

```
loverr.com/ockups304.jpg
```

I tried to change height from 52px to 92px, but still not getting as required

```
<div id="undefined-sticky-wrapper" class="my-wrapper" style="height: 52px;"><nav style="opacity: 1;">
```

**Please suggest me on this...**

Comment: Isn't this issue related 'jquery' and 'javascript'?

Answer (score 0):

Change the height in your CSS for `my-wrapper nav` like so:

```
.my-wrapper nav {
    height: 92px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the height on both the wrapper, which is the element you list in your question, and it's child the nav element, which inherits it's height from:

```
.my-wrapper nav {
```

Update the height in the css for that particular item and you should be ok.

Comment: Also for debugging things like this chrome developer tools, or Firefox with Firebug is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you have to adjust the nav style of your navigator (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDMew.png)
2. You can now adjust the **height** of the menu, as well as its **hover** effect and **bottom padding**.

You may also use a customized css.
Hope this answer will help.

Thanks,